# how to add something like a function or i dont know to use a multiple task on onClick

Tags: reactjs

```
 <TableBody>
                        {EncaissementsR.map((encaissementR, index) => (
    <StyledTableRow key={index}>
      <StyledTableCell>
        {encaissementR.numAvance}                                                   
                            </StyledTableCell>
                            <StyledTableCell align="right">{encaissementR.idEncaissement}</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="right">{encaissementR.dateEncaissement}</StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="right">{encaissementR.montantEncaissement}</StyledTableCell>

                            <StyledTableCell align="right" ><img onClick={this.props.onHide}  src={Money}></img></StyledTableCell>  
        </StyledTableRow>  

     ))}
                        </TableBody>**
```

okay there is a prop on the parent component so when i click on that img the modal goes off i want to add some thing like when i ckick on the image the modal goes down and another pops up to validate the payement**

Answer (score 0):

then write a function that calls both of these functions?

```
const hideModalAndValidatePayment = () => {
   hideFirstModal()
   showModalToValidatePayment()
}
```

Comment: the function of hidemodalfirst is not in the same componenet it procs when i call this.props.onHide , i wanna do something with this.props.onHide

Comment: then call `this.props.onHide` inside the function above?

Comment: xxx() {
  console.log('xxxx')
  this.props.onHide
}

Comment: it shows "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Comment: thats not the only probleme i fixed the first  , so i have this.props.onHide it make the second modal shut off because i have onHide={valideModalClose}, how can i solve that because i m using this.props.onHide

Comment: can you show the code with the line it's erroring on?